How to restrict user to not be able to pick ranged date on restricted daterange picker using syncfusion in flutter
so I am trying to make a date range picker using the syncfusion package in flutter where I want to make the user to not be able to pick at a certain dates which I did able to do, but the range picker is still allowing the date to be picked somehow, here's the example of the restricted date

as you can see, the date 20th june is disabled already, however, I am still able to get through it by doing this which I don't want the user to be able to do so, how to make the user unable to do this


As far as I know, Syncfusion doesn't have that feature in their lib yet, you can try custom blockDate in onSelectionChanged like this:
  final DateRangePickerController _controller = DateRangePickerController();
  final blockDate = DateTime(2024, 05, 27);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return SizedBox(
      height: 300.h,
      child: SfDateRangePicker(
        controller: _controller,
        selectableDayPredicate: (DateTime dateTime) {
          if (dateTime == blockDate) {
            return false;
          }
          return true;
        },
        onSelectionChanged: (DateRangePickerSelectionChangedArgs args) {
          final startDate = _controller.selectedRange?.startDate;
          final endDate = _controller.selectedRange?.endDate;

          if (startDate != null && startDate.isBefore(blockDate) && endDate != null && endDate.isAfter(blockDate)) {
            _controller.selectedRange = null;
          }
        },
      ),
    );
  }


The logic works just fine for me with a little bit of modification as my startDate and endDate is generated at initstate so it shouldn't be null but it gives some null error instead, but so far the code works just fine, thank you
